# Detailed calculation of the scattering amplitude between two particles in $\phi^4$-perturbation theory using the path integral formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral, feynman-diagrams

I'm looking for detailed example/calculation of the scattering amplitude between two particles (mesons) in $\phi^4$-perturbation theory using the path integral formalism. Do anyone of you guys have a good example to share? Maybe some old exercise of yours or a link to the web.

I'm using the book Quantum Field theory in a Nutshell and I'm currently reading chapter 1.7 (Feynman Diagrams) and I really wish there was a more detailed description of the calculations for the scattering amplitude of collision between particles. That's why I think an example would be of great educational help to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the book by David Bailin and Alexander Love on Gauge Theories?
[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Graduate-Student-Physics/dp/075030281X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/075030281X)
It contains the essence on scattering amplitudes all starting from the Green functions formalism which uses path integrals (thus no operators, no Wick theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Does the calculation starting from page 129 of [this note](http://theory.fi.infn.it/casalbuoni/lezioni99.pdf) by Casalbuoni is of any help to you? As far as I have understood question, it may help you out.

Also, [Critical properties of $\phi^4$ theories](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/phi4.pdf) by Hagen Kleinert is the most extensive reference for $\phi^4$ theory that I know of. Not widely known, at least in my experience, is a treasure trove for higher-order loop calculations, finding symmetry factor etc. Highly recommended for non-trivial details which are not easy to find elsewhere.